# switch case in where clause sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

How should i acheive this.. The problem lies in THEN part. I get error.
Basically i am trying to execute on the basis of parameter @Site and the values are more than one.
Therefore i am using IN clause but THEN part is giving error.

```
 :
 :     
 WHERE  
(
 @Site IN (CASE
    WHEN @Site = '1' THEN ('C150','C151','C152','C153','C154','C155','C158','C159','C160')
    WHEN @Site = '2' THEN ('C161','C162','C163','C164','C165','C166','C168','C169')
 END)
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: If @Site is either '1' or '2' it probably won't match any of the other choices. Do you really mean `WHERE 42 = 0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this

```
WHERE (@Site = '1' AND Site IN ('C150','C151'))
OR    (@Site='2' AND Site IN ('C161','C162'))
```

Not clear in your question, but I think you have a `@Site` var and a `Site` column.

Cause I don't see how `@Site` could be equal to `1` and in `C150`,.

Comment: Yes Site is Column and @Site is Parameter. I ran this and getting error saying "Incorrect Syntax near ','. (comma). Its working fine in Sql server but in SSRS report giving me error. So strange. what i am missing :)

Comment: Actually i am trying to get parameter value from multivalue drop down box and based on the option of 1 or 2, running a query to display a result in SSRS report. Hope this make sense. Thank

Comment: @AzyM well, there's no comma in your sample, so maybe show more code ?

Comment: Label || Value as (Disease1 || 1 and (Disease2 || 2) respectively

Comment: Please see the query above

Comment: @AzyM this is not your real query. This one wouldn't work in Sql Server (`Table A` should be `[Table A]` for example). By the way, error message should give you a line number. Which line is raising the error ?

Comment: I am still trying to work out but it helps thanks. i dont know why its not working in ssrs ??

Comment: Raphael, could you answer to my other expression question please if possible? Thanks